# suddenly below grade window

Tags: windows, grading

I am grading my 1965 house. Am new to this activity, and working my way around the entire house. I just removed several yews (remember how everyone planted them about a foot from the wall back then?) in front of 2 basement windows, and can now see that if I grade this wall to 6 degrees, these will be at least 2 inches below grade--no wonder my basement is collecting moisture!

These are not egress windows, but I need them for the natural light they provide in the basement.

I suspect that I will need to build window wells, but is there any SHORT TERM solution anyone could suggest that would allow me to finish the grading job and do the W.Wells next spring (I live in ME and time/weather for this stuff is running out! at this point).

To answer one of the  questions I received, I don't yet know enough about window wells to decide what kind to install. I will be taking the advice of the person who suggested just grading them  (for the time being) to just below the level of the windows, and would appreciate any more ideas and thoughts (and questions!)

Comment: Are these going to be 8 inch deep window "wells"?

Comment: "A picture is worth 1000 words"...

Comment: You can add a photo by clicking [edit] and then click the "sun and mountains" button. You can upload or paste a photo or photo link into the post. Or if you have a link to it already, put that link in your post and one of us can edit it in-line.

Comment: One of your edit comments indicates that you've added a picture, but I see no evidence of that. I did fix up the formatting a bit to add in the line breaks you'd intended - they need to `<enter>s` to actually cause a line break.

Answer (score 1):

Grade lower (all the way out away from the house) in front of those windows.

Comment: I am new on this site and am trying to figure out how to add a picture.  will do so when i have a chance....